# ScrollMagic Section Wipes (la animación no funciona)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

Porque razón no me hace el efecto de "Section Wipes" el ScrollMagic si he copiado tal cual el código:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

<title>D.disseny</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="panel blue">
        <b>ONE</b>
    </section>
    <section class="panel turqoise">
        <b>TWO</b>
    </section>
    <section class="panel green">
        <b>THREE</b>
    </section>
    <section class="panel bordeaux">
        <b>FOUR</b>
    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

---

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel.green {
    margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #3883d8;
}
.turqoise {
    background-color: #38ced7;
}
.green {
    background-color: #22d659;
}
.bordeaux {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 'onLeave'
    }
});

var slides = document.querySelectorAll("section.panel");

for (var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) {
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: slides[i]
        })
        .setPin(slides[i])
        .addIndicators() 
        .addTo(controller);
}
```

Comment: Has probado añadiendo los scripts al final del body?

Comment: @asantanao Si, incluso al principio solo por probar

Comment: Si ScrollMagic tiene dependencias en jQuery, jQuery debe ir primero. De todas formas, debes tener un error en consola. Cuál es?

Comment: En principio me sale el error "too much recursion" en la consola, que proviene del addIndicators. No conozco el plugin le echaré un vistazo a ver si veo el error. Por ahí deberías investigar en la documentación

Comment: @asantanao Justo he mirado ese problema, he puesto ambos plugins debajo del script "script.js" y no me ha salido mas el error.

Comment: Actualmente ninguno, recientemente he tenido uno por plugins pero los he movido de posición y ya no me han vuelto a dar problemas.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en ese código no se ve cómo estás invocando la función. Has puesto un breakpoint en tu código y te has asegurado que la ejecución pasa por ahi?

Comment: Así es, para poder hacer las pruebas directamente

Comment: Elimina el primer script de addIndicators, es repetitivo enlazar al archivo y a su formato .min, y de los dos, el .min es más adecuado para minimizar el peso de la carga en la página

Comment: @VictorMatilla pero si los pones así no podrás cargar el objeto scrollmagic

Comment: @asantanao He eliminado el que me has dicho y he puesto mi script debajo de todos los demás, he echo bien?

Comment: Tienes incluido dos veces uno de los scripts, en su versión completa y en la minificada. Además llamas a algunos scripts en http y no https. No sé qué hay en el css, pero el CSS es buena páctica ponerlo el primero, por si hay css funcional. Aqui parece que funciona bien, aunque no explicas qué quieres hacer https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wYMjqR (fíjate en el orden de la llamada a las dependencias)

Comment: yo lo pondría tal y como lo tienes en la pregunta, pero al final del body, para que los scripts carguen lo último. además para quitar el error debes hacer como te ha dicho @Carmen y borrar uno de los scripts de addIndicators, ya que están repetidos (uno minificado y otro normal).

Comment: @asantanao eso mismo hice esta mañana, ponerlos todos abajo del body y ya me iba todo perfecto, gracias!